# Realizar listas php en una tabla

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, lista, arraylist

Tengo el sisguiente requerimiento necesito asociar todos los datos de gastos comunes del mes con cada usuarios, ademas que si tiene gastos no comunes estos son individuales se asocien en un td a ese usuario, y al final se muestre cuanto debe aqui esta la primera tabla [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego hay que consultar esta segunda por si hay algun otro gasto 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para luego de asociar esta suma se muestre en el usuario en el ultimo td que dice el monto

aqui la tabla usuarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mis avance hasta el momento es mostar los gastos pero aun no logro asociar para que salga cada usuario con un td asociado a los gastos y su monto este es el codigo

```js
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Propietario</th>
  <th>Descripcion de gastos</th>
  <th>total a pagar</th>
 </tr>

<?php
   include 'conexion.php';
$sql = "SELECT descripcion,monto,factura,create_at FROM gasto_g";
  $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
while (list($descripcion,$monto,$factura,$create_at)=mysqli_fetch_array($res))  {
    echo " <tr>\n" .
    "  <td></a></td>\n" .
          "  <td>$descripcion</a></td>\n" .
          "  <td>$monto</td>\n" .
          " </tr>\n";
}

?>

</table>
```

Lo que espero es algo asi notandose que el 2do usuario tiene un gasto individual que no corresponde a otro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona de tu código? La pregunta no es clara.

Comment: necesito realizar asociacion de gastos_g que es los gastos generales, mostrar la descripcion y montos a todos los usuarios registrados en el sistema, ademas a este usuario en el mismo td se consulta si en gastnocmun tiene un gasto de ese mes asociado y mostrarlo y al lado el monto de los gatos, cada usuario en un td con tus respectivos gastos tanto los generales que es para todos como los individuales que es para cada uno

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de los resultados que esperas? No se entiende bien.  Y di si hay que calcular algo en el código o si todo viene ya calculado y sólo se trata de presentarlo.

Comment: Agregue al final de la pregunta lo que espero, en dado caso puede ser mostrado, yo me encargaria despues de los calculos no quiero causar tanto problema

Comment: Tus tablas necesitan ser normalizadas. Por ejemplo, ¿por qué columnas se relacionan entre sí las tres tablas?

Comment: La tabla gasto_g es de gastos generales, no tienen relacion con los usuarios ya que estas deben ser mostradas a todos ya que todos pagan este tipo de gasto, en la tabla gastonocmun es un gasto individual esa si esta relacionada a un usuario en especifico el cual le corresponde este gasto, por eso los gastos generales deben ser mostrados a todos y los individuales al usuario que le corresponde + los generales

Comment: Es problemático que la tabla `gasto_g` no tenga relación con la tabla de usuarios cuando sí se relacionan los datos pues dices que todos los usuarios tienen esos gastos generales. Además, no se sabe si en esa tabla hay varias filas y todas esa filas le corresponden a cada usuario ¿?  No sé, es un modelo de datos muy extraño según mi parecer.

Comment: en gasto_g los datos ingresados alli o gastos son para todos los usuarios su descrpcion y su monto la que es asociada a un usuario en especifico es la de gastonocmun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con Joins logre el objetivo, gracias a ambos por su tiempo

```
$sql = "SELECT relacion,relacionu,descripcion ,nombre,nombred,gasto 
        from gasto_g 
        RIGHT JOIN usuarios  ON usuarios.relacionu= gasto_g.relacion   
        LEFT JOIN gastonocmun   ON usuarios.nombre= gastonocmun.nombred 
        WHERE  MONTH( create_at) = '11'   ";
```

Answer (score 0):

hay varios errores en la normalización de la base de datos, pero para solo abstraerme a tu pregunta

deberías hacer un llamado a la tabla clientes también, para tener la condición de corte (por cliente, que es lo que estas pidiendo).

Entonces... no olvidar el Order By cliente

```
 $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

 //tendrias que validar que traiga datos 
 $clienteActual = $res("cliente") #asigno cliente actual (el primero)

while (list($descripcion,$monto,$factura,$create_at)=mysqli_fetch_array($res))  {

//pregunto si el cliente es el mismo que tengo guardado

if ($clienteActual = $cliente) {

      //si es el mismo, listo sus  datos
      echo " <tr>\n" .
      "  <td></a></td>\n" .
      "  <td>$descripcion</a></td>\n" .
      "  <td>$monto</td>\n" .
      " </tr>\n";

      #acumulo los gastos de este cliente
      $sumatoria = $sumatoria + $monto
}else {

      //si no es el mismo, muestro la sumatoria 

      //si tengo que mostrar otros datos de gastos personales, hacer otra consulta

      echo " <tr>\n" .
      "  <td></a></td>\n" .
      "  <td>$descripcion</a></td>\n" .
      "  <td>$sumatoria</td>\n" .
      " </tr>\n";
      //inicializo $sumatoria
      $sumatoria = 0
      //pongo el nuevo cliente como el actual
      $clienteActual = $cliente
 }
```

espero te sirva

otros consejos
la tabla debería tener la fecha del gasto, para filtrar los datos por el mes, aunque contablemente se usa un campo "fecha de imputación" para esas facturas de ultimo momento.
El campo enero y meses(los campos en singular) no tiene sentido, si son muchos podes crear una tabla totalizadora por mes, para evitar cálculos, pero para una liquidación de consorcio no es problema.

No coincide el nombre de la tabla en el select.

Comment: amigo en las tablas estan las entidades que guardan las fechas, dejame visualizar el codigo ya informo, gracias de antemano por tomarte el tiempo